# Is there a way to use embedded images from a view model

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a view model that gets and sets an Image Source. I don't know if this is correct or not.

```
public class animalsmodel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string AnimalNames { get; set; }

    public Button Animalselect { get; set; }

    public Button Back { get; set; }

    public ImageSource AnimalPhoto { get; set; }


}

}
```

I then use that in my list view. But it feels like I should call it from resource?

```
private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        alistview.ItemsSource = GetAnimals(e.NewTextValue);
    }

    IEnumerable<animalsmodel> GetAnimals(string searchText = null)
    {
        var animals = new List<animalsmodel>

        {
            new animalsmodel() { id = 1, AnimalNames = "Aardvark", **AnimalPhoto** = ("AppSFari.Images.Aardvark.jpg")},
```

And then I use it in my XAML file. The name displays and I can see where the image should be but it is blank. And I have set the image in my project to Embedded Resource.

```
<ListView x:Name="alistview" BackgroundColor ="AliceBlue" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="alistview_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding AnimalPhoto}" Text="{Binding AnimalNames}"/>
                           
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: you can just specify the image name as a string and XF will load it from the appropriate location

Comment: I have tried that. I just made it a public string but the image still doesn't show.

Comment: is the image in the shared project's resources?  Or in the platform projects?

Comment: In platform projects. Is there a certain resolution for [imagecell] images? when I put a normal image in [mainpage] it works. But it just doesn't show in my [listview].

Comment: no, it should work the same inside of a ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally incorrect .

About how to use embedded images pls check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#xaml).

`ProvideValue` methods only trigers when we set **static** string in xaml with the following way

```
 <Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg}" />
```

In another word , embedded images can only be hard-corded in xaml but not in code .

---

#### Correct way

Place the image into specific platform project , iOS -> image assets/Resources  , Android ->Resources .

Do not use embedded image, use  local image, you could refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-listview-customcells/

#### Update

Change the type of parameters of Aardvark's constructor .

```
    public Aardvark(String AnimalNames, Button Animalselect, Button Back, string PhotoSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AnimalNameCall.Text = AnimalNames;
        addanimal = Animalselect;
        terug = Back;
        dierfoto.Image = PhotoSource;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much I got it to work. Just didn't know you have to hard code embedded images. Just one more question if you have a look at my AnimalPage:ContentPage at he bottom i handle the selected item to open to a new page where the buttons and the animals name is added. How do i get the image to be added? when i try it says it can't convert from string to image

Comment: `var animals = e.SelectedItem as ImageResourceExtention;  string image = animals.PhotoSource`  Does the code works or not ?

Comment: dierfoto is image you should set image in class constructor , `dierfoto.Image = PhotoSource; .`

Comment: I did try that but i get a error that "Image does not contain a definition for Image". Because dierfoto is a `<Image>` in xaml

Comment: dierfoto.Source=PhotoSource

Comment: I got it to work thank a million for the help. I just changed it back to what it was `var animals = e.SelectedItem as animalsmodel` and used the `dierfoto.Source = AnimalPhoto`

Comment: If problem gets solved , could you accept my solution as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help so far. So this is what I have done, I use this as my view model for the list view.

```
class ImageResourceExtention : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string PhotoSource { get; set; }
        public string AnimalNames { get; set; }

        public Button Back { get; set; }
        public Button Animalselect { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (PhotoSource == null) 
            {

                return null;
            
            }

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(PhotoSource, typeof(ImageResourceExtention).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

            return imageSource;       
        
        }

    }
```

Then my list view will have a id, animal name, and lastly a image. This is how I did it. I don't know if the image part is correct?

```
  public partial class AnimalsPage : ContentPage

        
        
    {
        
        private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            alistview.ItemsSource = GetAnimals(e.NewTextValue);
        }

        IEnumerable<ImageResourceExtention> GetAnimals(string searchText = null)
        {
            var animals = new List<ImageResourceExtention>

            {
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 1, AnimalNames = "Aardvark", PhotoSource = "AppSFari.Images.Aardvark.jpg"},
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 2, AnimalNames = "Aardwolf", PhotoSource = "AppSFari.Images.Aardwolf.jpg" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 3, AnimalNames = "Baboon" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 4, AnimalNames = "Bat-eared Fox" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 5, AnimalNames = "Black Backed Jackel" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 6, AnimalNames = "Black Rhino" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 7, AnimalNames = "Black Wildebeest" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 8, AnimalNames = "Brown Hyena" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 9, AnimalNames = "Buffalo" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 10, AnimalNames = "Bush Pig" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 11, AnimalNames = "Bushbuck" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 12, AnimalNames = "Cape Grysbok" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 13, AnimalNames = "Caracal" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 14, AnimalNames = "Cheetah" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 15, AnimalNames = "Common Duiker" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 16, AnimalNames = "Eland" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 17, AnimalNames = "Gemsbok/Oryx" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 18, AnimalNames = "Giraffe" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 19, AnimalNames = "Hippo" },
                new ImageResourceExtention() { id = 20, AnimalNames = "Impala" },
            };
            
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText))
                return animals;
            var lowerAnimals = searchText.ToLower();
            return animals.Where(c => c.AnimalNames.ToLower().StartsWith(lowerAnimals));
        }



    public AnimalsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            alistview.ItemsSource = GetAnimals();
            BindingContext = this;
            
         }

       async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await myScrollview.ScrollToAsync(1, alistview.Y, true);
        }

       async private void alistview_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var animals = e.SelectedItem as ImageResourceExtention;
            
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Aardvark(animals.AnimalNames, animals.Animalselect, animals.Back));
        }

       async private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

Then in my content page the list and search bar all works but where the image should be it is blank.

```
       x:Class="AppSFari.Kwandwe_Pakage.AnimalsPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppSFari.Kwandwe_Pakage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView HeightRequest="3000" x:Name="myScrollview">
            <AbsoluteLayout>
                
                       
                <StackLayout>
                <SearchBar 
                    TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged"
                    Placeholder="Search Animal"
                    PlaceholderColor="Gray"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    FontAttributes="Italic"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                <ListView x:Name="alistview" BackgroundColor ="AliceBlue" 
                          HasUnevenRows="True"
                          ItemSelected="alistview_ItemSelected">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding PhotoSource}" Aspect="AspectFit" 
                                               HeightRequest="60" 
                                               WidthRequest="60"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding AnimalNames}" TextColor="Black" 
                                               FontFamily="appfontM"
                                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    
                                </ViewCell>

                            </DataTemplate>

                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Button Text="Back to top" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Back" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="8" 
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,0.2,0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Sorry if I am making silly mistakes I am new to this.